# Connection Manager is not working

Tags: gazebo-tutorial, gazebo-1.5

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I got this when I try to run gazebo:

```
Error [Server.cc:238] Could not open file[worlds/empty.world]

Error [ConnectionManager.cc:89] Connection Manager is not running
```

I have no idea what has happened because it was working for me some time.
I tried to reinstall gazebo and follow instructions that I found in Internet but none of them helped.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2195/connection-manager-is-not-working/) by [MoonWalker](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/248/moonwalker/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wonyoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/279/wonyoung/) on 2013-04-05**:
I have a same problem. I've just changed my system into 64 bit for Gazebo 1.5 and drcsim. But, I got this problem.

**Comment by [Wonyoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/279/wonyoung/) on 2013-04-05**:
In my case, I have rebooted my machine and tried again. And it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This error:

```
Error [Server.cc:238] Could not open file[worlds/empty.world]
```

suggests that something is wrong with your environment setup.  Probably you didn't source `/usr/share/drcsim/setup.sh` before trying to launch the simulator.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MoonWalker](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/248/moonwalker/) on 2013-04-06**:
Thanks, you were right.